# Responsive Wordpress table problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

Good Afternoon,

I'm very much a beginner, so hang with me here... I am helping to design the website for our company and we have a header at the top of the page that is filled with anchors for our spectators to navigate through our page. However, the table completely falls apart whenever we try to scale it down to our mobile or tablet size.

The table is all built on percentages and I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Here is the code to the entire table, including the anchors:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<table class=" aligncenter" style="width: 74%; height: 30px;" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25%; text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom;" scope="row">
<h4>                  Web Commercial</h4>
</td>
<td style="width: 60%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;" scope="row"><span style="color: #808080;">         <a href="#cameras"><span style="color: #808080;">Cameras</span></a>    <a href="#directors"><span style="color: #808080;">Directors</span></a>     <a href="#branded"><span style="color: #808080;">Branded Content</span></a>     <a href="#mediadelivery"><span style="color: #808080;">Media Delivery</span></a>     <a href="#resolution"><span style="color: #808080;">Resolution</span></a>     <a href="#pricing"><span style="color: #808080;">Pricing</span></a></span></td>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom;" scope="row"><span style="color: #808080;">       <img class="alignnone wp-image-1604 size-full" src="http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Buy-Now-actual-size-2.png" alt="" width="65" height="33" /></span></td>
<td style="width: 100%;" scope="row"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1526" src="http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Line.jpg" alt="" width="920" height="1" />
```

Here is the website: http://visualicreative.com/products/advertising/web-commercial-html/

Here is a screenshot of what i'm talking about: https://flic.kr/p/nU3ita

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i've exhausted myself trying to fix this problem. Plugin suggestions that enable you to quickly create tables for formatting (create 2 or 3 different columns) purposes are warmly welcomed.

Much appreciated.

JE

Comment: Using a table for navigation!? YIKES! My suggestion: don't use tables. Very dated technology.

Comment: Tables are not for laying out navigation. An unordered list (`<ul>`) will suffice.

Comment: Personally I'd use divs, tables are a very old fashioned way of doing things that can lead to a lot of frustration when being used alongside modern technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace the whole table with something like this: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j2eeW/1/)**

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav cf">
    <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* navigation styles */
.nav { width:100%; margin:0 auto; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.nav li{ float:left; }
.nav li a { display:inline-block; margin:10px; padding:10px; background:#eee; }

/* media-query - resize window to see. */
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav li { width:100%;float:none; }
    .nav li a { display:block; margin:10px; padding:10px; }

}


/* micro clear fix hack. */
.cf:before,
.cf:after { content: " "; display: table;   }
.cf:after { clear: both;  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I took your advice and removed the table and put in the <ul class> code like you suggested. After I got done modifying it back to the look I want (removed the bullets and changed the font color and spacing,) it appears to be very close to what we're going for. However, and even though it scales better than before, it's still not scaling down properly to a mobile device. Do you have any other suggestions that could help? I really don't want to alter from the way it currently looks.

http://visualicreative.com/products/advertising/web-commercial-html/

Comment: @Jeffrey9896 How do you want it to appear on a mobile device? 1 link per line?

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks again for the response. I photoshopped an image to show you what I'm after. If I could get anywhere close to it visually looking like this in mobile mode, I'd be very happy.

https://flic.kr/p/nU9z4B

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**A CSS ONLY RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MENU BAR** *(no javascript required)*

### CLICK FOR DEMO

```
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

*Courtesy of [media loot](http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/)*